# ionic angular, child component wont display

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes

What i want is to render, delete.component inside view-store-list.component. I dont understand why it wont display. In my knowledge i have done eveything correctly.
I have already added the child component(delete.component) in my module, i have this problem for a while and i just cant figure it out. Can you guys shed some light on me.

//rating.module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
.....

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ViewStoreListComponent,
    DeleteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RatingRoutingModule,
    IonicModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
```

export class RatingModule { }

//rating-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewAddRatingComponent } from './views/view-add-rating/view-add-rating.component';
import { ViewStoreListComponent } from './views/view-store-list/view-store-list.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path : '', redirectTo: 'store-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'store-list', component: ViewStoreListComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RatingRoutingModule { }
```

//view-store-list.html

```
<app-delete></app-delete>    <---- this wont display
<p>Heelo</p>                 <---- this would display
```

//delete.component.html

```
<div>
  <h1>DELETE COMPONENT</h1>
</div>
```

//delete.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete',
  templateUrl: './delete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete.component.scss'],
})
export class DeleteComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('FROM DELETE COMPONENT');
    
  }

}
```

Comment: add your deleteComponent code, and also add the message you are seeing (if any) in the console

Comment: @Moshezauros, i have updated my post, also there is no erro in console

Comment: did you declare DeleteComponent in you app.module.ts file?

Comment: this looks correct to me, make sure all files are saved, and try to stop the ng serve process and start it again

Comment: i dont think, i need to declare delete component, in my app.module, since im just going to use it in my rating module, yap  i have tried stopping it and running it again. Issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

Export DeleteComponentModule:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DeleteRoutingModule } from './delete-routing.module';
import { DeleteComponent } from './delete.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [DeleteComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DeleteRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports:[DeleteComponent]
})
export class DeleteComponentModule { }
```

Import this module in **rating.module**, instead of component:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ViewStoreListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RatingRoutingModule,
    IonicModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    DeleteComponentModule //import here
  ]
})
```